# Unable to make QQuickWidget show taskbar shortcut

Tags: qt, qquickwidget

I am unable to make my QQuickWidget, launched as a popup, show a taskbar shortcut in Windows.

**Details of the problem:**

I have an application that is hosted inside a "suite", which uses `QWinHost` to make all children apps lodge inside. This method has always created issues with popup windows, which even though modal to the application, can hide behind the "suite" window. For now, the solution has been to give popups a taskbar icon, which blinks when the user tries to access the application - non-responding while the popup is behind.

When I launch the `QQuickWidget`, from the application, I am unable to get the taskbar shortcut.

I am setting null parent because the application has lots of widgets and no matter what parent I give it, there would be siblings (or cousins)

```
m_qqWidget = new QQuickWidget(Q_NULLPTR);
m_qqWidget->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("QmlThing", m_libQml);
m_qqWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
m_qqWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop, true);
m_qqWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Dialog);  // Tried others too
m_qqWidget->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
m_qqWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/QmlThing.qml"));
m_qqWidget->show();
```

What can I do to make my QQuickWidget show the taskbar shortcut when launched, and blink when the thing that launched it is clicked ?

Platform: Windows, Qt version 5.12